# how to use tensorflow object detection API for face detection

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, face-detection

Open CV provides a simple API to detect and extract faces from given images. ( I do not think it works perfectly fine though because I experienced that it cuts frames from the input pictures that have nothing to do with face images. )

I wonder if tensorflow API can be used for face detection. I failed finding relevant information but hoping that maybe an experienced person in the field can guide me on this subject. Can tensorflow's object detection API be used for face detection as well in the same way as Open CV does? (I mean, you just call the API function and it gives you the face image from the given input image.)

Comment: If you like Python, You could ready built solutions like https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition or https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/ .

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! Still ondering though what is (not) possible with tensorflow's object detection API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but some work is needed.
First, take a look at the object detection [README](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). There are some useful articles you should follow. Specifically: (1) Configuring an object detection pipeline, (3) Preparing inputs and (3) Running locally. You should start with an existing architecture with a pre-trained model. Pretrained models can be found in [Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md), and their corresponding configuration files can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs).
The most common pre-trained models in Model Zoo are on COCO dataset. Unfortunately this dataset doesn't contain face as a class (but does contain person).
Instead, you can start with a pre-trained model on Open Images, such as faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid, which does contain face as a class.
Note that this model is larger and slower than common architectures used on COCO dataset, such as SSDLite over MobileNetV1/V2. This is because Open Images has a lot more classes than COCO, and therefore a well working model need to be much more expressive in order to be able to distinguish between the large amount of classes and localizing them correctly.
Since you only want face detection, you can try the following two options:

1. If you're okay with a slower model which will probably result in better performance, start with faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid, and you can only slightly fine-tune the model on the single class of face.
2. If you want a faster model, you should probably start with something like SSDLite-MobileNetV2 pre-trained on COCO, but then fine-tune it on the class of face from a different dataset, such as your own or the face subset of Open Images. 
   Note that the fact that the pre-trained model isn't trained on faces doesn't mean you can't fine-tune it to be, but rather that it might take more fine-tuning than a pre-trained model which was pre-trained on faces as well.

Answer (score 0):

just increase the shape of the input, I tried and it's work much better

Comment: More sophisticated answer will be great.